# Angular 7 sticky footer with bootstrap4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, angular7

I'm learning angular7 and I would create a sticky footer. I've tried a lot of solutions.

I tried :

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/
- some solution in stackoverflow
- some solution found via google search (like [this](https://medium.com/@JSantaCL/pure-bootstrap-sticky-footer-with-flex-and-angular-e207abf505c7))

No one works for me. I don't understand why, and I need help.

I have this code after removing all I've tried:

*app.module.ts*

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    FooterComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*index.html (just the body)*

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

*app.component.html*

```html
<app-menu></app-menu>

<main class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>

<div class="footer mt-auto py-3">
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

*footer.component.html*

```html
<footer>
  &copy; 2019 - Zackna
</footer>
```

Edit: I update my codes with @avcajaraville answer that I have already tried but removed ^-^. And there is 
[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMPrG.png), as you can see my footer is not sticky to the bottom of the page.

Is a bootstrap native solution exists? My footer does not have a definitive height. What do I need to do to achieve my goal?

Comment: Did you add the corresponding CSS to your app?

Comment: Do you mean the bootstrap CSS? Yes, jquery and popper.js too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code samples, you are not adding the classes you need.

You can fix that by mimicking the same structure as in the example you provided:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="h-100">
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

app.component.html

```
<app-menu></app-menu>
<main class="container">
  <h1>title</h1>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
<div class="footer mt-auto py-3">
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

I think this would give you the expected behavior.

In general, when working with a CSS framework, you need to use the classes specified in your html. Otherwise, no CSS can be applied.

**EDIT**

I added the needed class on the html tag in your index.html file & refactor app.component.html

Comment: I've updated my post, I think I do it wrong 'cause it does not work.

Comment: @Zackna updated my code. You were missing the class `h-100` on the html element.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @avcajaraville for the answer.
Unfortunately, I missed the class h-100 when I tried it and I don't see i:/

In the meantime, I found a solution.

I added this CSS to my app-root component:

```css
app-root {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

and a `flex-grow: 1;` to my container class.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this if you want to just use the bootstrap utility classes and not write custom css using app-root's component css or custom css via :host

In your index.html do this,

```
<html class="h-100">
<head>....omitted</html>
<body class="h-100">
    <app-root class="d-flex flex-column h-100"></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

to recap, if you're following the sticky footer example from Bootstrap4 website using Angular then you need to put the utility class on app-root not the body and make sure just height of body element is set to 100% using h-100 (also need h-100 on html element as well!!)

Answer (score 0):

This will always calculate the total height set the min-height for the content div for me the 202px was perfect.This will push the footer at the bottom.

```
              .main-content {
                  min-height: calc(100vh - 202px);
               }


                  <main>
                      <div class="main-content"></div>
                      <app-footer class="footer"></app-footer>
                 </main>
```